# Is it possible to globally remove a vue component from the global registry?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I would like to remove a components from Vue at runtime that was previously registered with Vue.component(name, {...}), is this possible ?

We are creating a number of components on the fly in a live development setting and would like to remove old components from memory.

Or is it possible to alter the child components registered with a component at runtime ? Only affecting new component instances built after that of course or refreshed manually.

Comment: `Vue.component('my-component1', () => null);` will supplant the component with a minimal function. It will still exist, but not render anything.

Comment: this is an interesting approach.. will give it a try. at the very least this should minimize the dependency chain

Answer (score 4):

Currently in Vue 2.x, when you register a component with `Vue.component` it's added to the base constructor options object. You can unregister it by simply deleting the component from the components object:

```js
Vue.component('child-component', ChildComponent)

delete Vue.options.components['child-component']
```

Comment: Is this still a solution for Vue3?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do the trick for you

```
wm.$destroy()
```

[Documentation for Destroy](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-destroy)

Comment: That will destroy a vm, but components are registered on the Vue object.

Answer (score 0):

To display all components:

```
this.$options.components
```

To delete a specific component:

`delete this.$options.components.NameOfComponent`

Comment: this only shows you the locally registered components, the OP specifically asks for the globally registered components

Answer (score 0):

In Vue 3 this works:

```
delete app._context.components["NameOfComponent"]
```